# Reduce on Pojo field with Apache Flink using Java

Tags: java, aggregate, min, reduce, apache-flink

I'm building a benchmarking tool for some distributed processing tools at the moment, and have some trouble with Apache Flink.

The setup is simple: LogPojo is a simple Pojo with three fields (long date, double value, String data). Out of a List I'm looking for the one LogPojo with the minimum "value" field. Basically the equivalent to:

```
pojoList.stream().min(new LogPojo.Comp()).get().getValue();
```

My flink setup looks like:

```
public double processLogs(List<LogPojo> logs) {

    final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    DataSet<LogPojo> logSet = env.fromCollection(logs);

    double result = 0.0;
    try {
        ReduceOperator ro = logSet.reduce(new LogReducer());
        List<LogPojo> c = ro.collect();
        result = c.get(0).getValue();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught" + ex);
    }

    return result;
}

public class LogReducer implements ReduceFunction<LogPojo> {

    @Override
    public LogPojo reduce(LogPojo o1, LogPojo o2) {
        return (o1.getValue() < o2.getValue()) ? o1 : o2;
    }
}
```

It stops with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$.empty()Lscala/collection/immutable/HashSet;
```

So somehow it seems to be unable to apply the reduce function. I just can't find, why. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should check your imports. You get an exception from a Scala class but your program is implemented in Java. You might have accidentally imported the Scala DataSet API. Using the Java API should not result in a Scala exception (unless you are using classes which depend on Scala).

Regardless of that, Flink has a built-in aggregation methods for `min`, `max`, etc.

```
DataSet<LogPojo> logSet = env.fromCollection(logs);
// map LogPojo to a Tuple1<Double> 
//   (Flink's built-in aggregation functions work only on Tuple types)
DataSet<Tuple1<Double>> values = logSet.map(new MapFunction<LogPojo, Tuple1<Double>>() {
    @Override
    public Tuple1<Double> map(LogPojo l) throws Exception {
      return new Tuple1<>(l.value);
    }
  });
// fetch the min value (at position 0 in the Tuple)
List<Tuple1<Double>> c = values.min(0).collect();
// get the first field of the Tuple
Double minVal = c.get(0).f0;
```

Comment: Thank you, the hint about the import solved it. It seems one of the spark scala dependencies was wreaking havoc. Once I disabled the spark module, it works.